# Why does this line indefinitely repeat?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, stack, subclassing

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCellFixed *cell = (UITableViewCellFixed *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

the second line (ie: the first line after the function is declared) is repeating itself indefinitely. I have no idea why.

I got a stack overload when I was running the script, and when I put a breakpoint on this line and subsequent lines in the same method this line just continuously repeats and the breakpoints never move onto the next one.

I have no idea why this is, but this is my first time trying to subclass a UITextViewCell, so I'm assuming I've done something wrong?

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ask your table for a cell, the table itself calls `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to be able to display the cell in correct height.

Comment: oh right... :p *embarassed* so, how would I get the cell textLabel and detailTextLabel objects?

Comment: You should get the contents of these labels from your model rather than from the cell itself.

Comment: in –tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: ah fair enough, good idea. :) @simon, thanks but I need the text in order to set the appropriate height. :)